# Shell command to copy just html files to the correct folder

Tags: shell, typescript, npm

I'm creating a build script using npm.

The build script includes typescript compiling.

The typescript compiling copies the folder structure from a ts folder to a dist/js folder.

The ts folder is like

```
ts
--  one
    -- one.html
    -- one.ts

    two
    -- two.html
    -- two.ts
```

And the dist/js folder created is like

```
js
--  one
    -- one.js

    two
    -- two.js
```

The ts folders always contain html that I need to copy to the js after the compiling has run.

What shell command can I use to copy the html from the ts folder to the correct folder in the outputed js folder.

**Update**

I have tried the following command

```
"build:copy-html": "find ./app/ts -name '*.html' cp ./dist/js \\;",
```

but get an error of

find: cp: unknown primary or operator

**UPDATE**

In the ts folder I have

```
    ts
    --home
        --home.html
        --home.ts
```

I need the js folder to be

```
    js
    --home
        --home.html
        --home.js
```

Comment: `find`, `cpio`, and `tar` are your friends

Comment: GMichael I have looked into your suggestion and updated my question, can you offer any more advise how I might do this.

Comment: Look at the *man*-page of `find`: For running a command on the files being found, you need to use the `-exec` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do the following:

```
  (cd app/ts; tar -cf - `find . -name '*.html' `) | (cd app/dist/js ; tar -xf -)
```

I suppose that you want to copy all the '*.html' files from `app/ts` to `app/js` directory keeping the directory structure and there are no spaces in the file names.

There are some more methods. `find` and `cpio` combination usually appears in the manual page of `find` like here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: GMichael how would that work in my script like - `"build:copy-html": "tar -cf - `cd app/ts; find . -name '*.html' ` | (cd app/js ; tar -xf -)",`

Comment: If I run the script I gat an error - `sh: line 0: cd: app/js: No such file or directory
tar: ./home/home.html: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`

Comment: @ttmt  What is the real full path of `app/ts`?

Comment: The ts folder is at app/ts and the js is at app/dist/js I updated the code as so `"build:copy-html": "tar -cf - `cd app/ts; find . -name '*.html' ` | (cd app/dist/js ; tar -xf -)",` Now I get the error -  `tar: ./home/home.html: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`

Comment: The first `cd` was wrong. I've changed the answer. Please check it.